# React hooks. Why doesn't set function change state?

Tags: reactjs, state, react-hooks

```
const Navbar = () => {
  const prevScrollY = React.useRef<number>();

  const [isHidden, setIsHidden] = React.useState(false);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const onScroll = () => {
      const scrolledDown = window.scrollY > prevScrollY.current!;
      console.log(`is hidden ${isHidden}`);
      if (scrolledDown && !isHidden) {
        setIsHidden(true);
        console.log(`set hidden true`);
      } else if (!scrolledDown && isHidden) {
        console.log(`set hidden false. THIS NEVER HAPPENS`);
        setIsHidden(false);
      }

      prevScrollY.current = window.scrollY;
    };

    console.log("adding listener");

    window.addEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", onScroll);
    };
  }, []);

  return isHidden ? null : <div>navbar</div>;
};
```

[Full example](https://codesandbox.io/s/x9kln60z04?fontsize=14)

The `` console.log(`is hidden ${isHidden}`); `` always prints false, and the `setIsHidden(true)` always gets triggered but never seems to change the state. Why? Basically the isHidden is never setto false, except after the useState initialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically what happens is that your `useEffect` runs only twice on mount and on unmount (*and that's apparently intentional*), however the unwanted side-effect of this is that the value of `isHidden` that you're checking against in the `onScroll` method gets closured at it's initial value (which is `false`) - forever (*until the unmount that is*).

You could use functional form of the setter, where it receives the actual value of the state and put all the branching logic inside it. Something like:

```
  setIsHidden(isHidden => { // <- this will be the proper one
     const scrolledDown = window.scrollY > prevScrollY.current!;
     console.log(`is hidden ${isHidden}`);
     if (scrolledDown && !isHidden) {
        console.log(`set hidden true`);
        return true;  
      } else if (!scrolledDown && isHidden) {
        console.log(`set hidden false. THIS NEVER HAPPENS`);
        return false;
      } else {
        // ...
```

Comment: Thanks. But "else ..." else what? The thing is that whatever I return in the else the state is going to be updated, which it shouldn't. The goal is to update state only if the 2 if statements are true, otherwise, don't set new state. The solution above will always update state, on every single scroll. Which will also re-render the whole component.

Comment: To be honest, the way I've written my question, your first paragraph answers it perfectly. I created a [separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55023041/react-hooks-how-to-implement-usehideonscroll-hook), that extends on this one. So, just the first part of your answer should be sufficient.

Comment: I wasn't sure what exactly you were up to, so didn't complete the piece. I'm going to post a full snippet in your other question.